# How to read system properties from .properties file

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

I have a JAVA web application which runs on Tomcat Server. I have a setup a property in my tomcat’s VM arguments; something like -Denvironment =“E1”.

I want to read that property inside my app.properties file, I tried mutiple options like ${environment} and {sys:environment} but could not able to read the value.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one:

```
${sys:environment}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately didn’t work. did I worked for you?

Comment: Would you try System.getProperty("environment") in your code?

Comment: I want to read the value in .properties File. So System.getProperty won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the class you are using to load your properties, because Java dont support this.

If you try with

${sys:environment}

You should use Commons-Configuration

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/